# Error "missing path" while running 'gulp test' in js-stellar-base

Tags: javascript-sdk

I cloned the js-stellar-base and then ran 'gulp test' and it returned the following error:

```
 Using gulpfile /mnt/c/Users/Debchakra/Desktop/js-stellar-base/gulpfile.js
[00:01:03] Starting 'test'...
[00:01:03] Starting 'clean'...
[00:01:03] 'clean' errored after 44 ms
[00:01:03] AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: missing path
    at Module.require (module.js:594:3)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at requireFn (/mnt/c/Users/Debchakra/Desktop/js-stellar-base/node_modules/gulp-load-plugins/index.js:37:14)
    at Object.get (/mnt/c/Users/Debchakra/Desktop/js-stellar-base/node_modules/gulp-load-plugins/index.js:59:18)
    at Gulp.<anonymous> (/mnt/c/Users/Debchakra/Desktop/js-stellar-base/gulpfile.js:107:21)
    at module.exports (/mnt/c/Users/Debchakra/Desktop/js-stellar-base/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:34:7)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (/mnt/c/Users/Debchakra/Desktop/js-stellar-base/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:273:3)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep (/mnt/c/Users/Debchakra/Desktop/js-stellar-base/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:214:10)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator.start (/mnt/c/Users/Debchakra/Desktop/js-stellar-base/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:134:8)
    at runNextSet (/mnt/c/Users/Debchakra/Desktop/js-stellar-base/node_modules/run-sequence/index.js:86:16)
[00:01:03] 'test' errored after 74 ms
[00:01:03] AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION] in plugin 'run-sequence(clean)'
Message:
    missing path
Details:
    generatedMessage: false
    code: ERR_ASSERTION
    actual: null
    expected: true
    operator: ==
Stack:
AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: missing path
    at Module.require (module.js:594:3)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at requireFn (/mnt/c/Users/Debchakra/Desktop/js-stellar-base/node_modules/gulp-load-plugins/index.js:37:14)
    at Object.get (/mnt/c/Users/Debchakra/Desktop/js-stellar-base/node_modules/gulp-load-plugins/index.js:59:18)
    at Gulp.<anonymous> (/mnt/c/Users/Debchakra/Desktop/js-stellar-base/gulpfile.js:107:21)
    at module.exports (/mnt/c/Users/Debchakra/Desktop/js-stellar-base/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:34:7)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (/mnt/c/Users/Debchakra/Desktop/js-stellar-base/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:273:3)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep (/mnt/c/Users/Debchakra/Desktop/js-stellar-base/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:214:10)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator.start (/mnt/c/Users/Debchakra/Desktop/js-stellar-base/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:134:8)
    at runNextSet (/mnt/c/Users/Debchakra/Desktop/js-stellar-base/node_modules/run-sequence/index.js:86:16)
```

I tried to Google this error, was not find something that will resolve this.

Note: I am running this on WSL(Windows Subsystem for Linux)

Please let me know, if any further information is required

Answer (score 1):

The version of Node installed on my system was 11.6.0, I changed it to 11.1.0 and the error was resolved.